# iPad app doesn't render site icons correctly on iOS 10

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

The left nav bar has a distorted display of the various other Stack Exchange sites when the app is launched on iOS 10.

Screenshot:

[image]

- App version: 1.5.3.5
- Device: iPad Air (Wi-Fi)
- OS version: 10.0 (build 14A5297c)

Comment: By distorter, did you mean "white square"? If it's then it's a dupe of [Site logos showing with white box in app on iOS 10 Beta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281056/site-logos-showing-with-white-box-in-app-on-ios-10-beta)

Comment: @meatball: yes, same issue. It seems I reported it before the other but mine is specifically for iPad where as the other is on an iPhone. Either way, same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in a later iOS beta.

Comment: Seems fixed now as 9.10.2016. How do I close this bug report?

Comment: @keno nothing you need to do. I marked it as status-completed which takes it off my list.

Comment: @keno you сould also accept this answer.