# Site logos showing with white box in app on iOS 10 Beta

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

As you can see in the below screenshot, some of the the icons (e.g. Stack Overflow, User Experience, and more) are showing with white box around them.

> [image: site logos not showing correctly]

- App Version: 1.5.3.5
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.0 (Build 14A5297c)

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: I've seen this on a few apps. The location marker on Google Maps also has it.

Comment: I'm on an iPhone 5s, if it helps any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was fixed in iOS 10 public beta #3. Everything seems to be fine for now. Update to it and all of these bugs in apps *Should* be fixed.