# Bug iOS 10 square icons

Tags: bug, ios-app

---

### It seems that iOS 10 Public Beta 3 fixed all of this. All is good.

---

I've found this bug on mobile where some icons have white squares on them. Is this already reported? Or is this supposed to happen? I am on iOS 10 public beta #1…

[image]

- App Version: 1.5.3.5
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 10.0 (Build 14A5297c)

Also it happened on mobile site...

[image]

Comment: Answer to the off topic question: no, you won't get any automatic question ban, as long as the questions are not also heavily downvoted.

Comment: @meatball I knew there would be another question, I just couldn't find it. iOS ten beta has been out a long time and it's bound to have been reported already.

Comment: @ShadowWizard also, my badges appear bigger than they should, for some reason.

Comment: re: huge badge, [Badge indicator is too large relative to other text on Android App](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243726/badge-indicator-is-too-large-relative-to-other-text-on-android-app) (and it's related links). It's because of the system font used by the app (whether on Android or iOS).

Comment: This is a dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281056/314868

Comment: @miken32 besides the text at the top that says it's a duplicate, I think I know.

Comment: Sorry, not sure how I missed that it was already closed.