# Site icons have white backgrounds on iOS 10

Tags: bug, ios-app

[image: Screenshot]

- App Version: 1.5.3.5
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.0 (Build 14A5309d)

Comment: I actually realized that this is already reported at http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281056/314868 it could be closed I guess.

Comment: You can close it yourself by accepting the duplicate.

Comment: Patrick, where would I have the option of accepting the duplicate?

Comment: There should be a banner on top of your question. Maybe it is only there on the website, not in the app.

Comment: @Patrick indeed, the app doesn't support it, only the web version.